# ERROR unknown variable > 'keyring_okv_conf_dir=/usr/local/mysql/mysql-keyring-okv'

Tags: mysql

Env: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS + MySQL 5.7.32

I have a KMIP server working and tested. I am now trying to configuring Keyring to enable symmetric key encryption on my database

Per official docs, I added the following lines to /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so
keyring_okv_conf_dir=/usr/local/mysql/mysql-keyring-okv
```

restarting mysql:

```
uadmin@Linux01:/var/keyring$ sudo service mysql restart
[sudo] password for uadmin:
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error
```

code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

```
> -- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down. Nov 18 08:53:12 Linux01 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
> -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
> -- Defined-By: systemd
> -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
> --
> -- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up. Nov 18 08:53:12 Linux01 mysql-systemd-start[117506]: ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server: Nov
> 18 08:53:12 Linux01 mysql-systemd-start[117506]:
**> 2020-11-18T13:53:12.240218Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable
> 'keyring_okv_conf_dir=/usr/local/mysql/mysql-keyring-okv' Nov 18**
> 08:53:12 Linux01 mysql-systemd-start[117506]:
> 2020-11-18T13:53:12.242657Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting Nov 18 08:53:12 Linux01
> mysql-systemd-start[117506]: Please take a look at
> https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common
> upgrade issues. Nov 18 08:53:12 Linux01 mysql-systemd-start[117506]:
> Once the problem is resolved, restart the service. Nov 18 08:53:12
> Linux01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited
> status=1 Nov 18 08:53:12 Linux01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed
> with result 'exit-code'. Nov 18 08:53:12 Linux01 systemd[1]: Failed to
> start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: Comment `keyring_okv_conf_dir`. Try to load the server. Ensure that the plugin was loaded successfully.

Comment: I have .... commenting kerying_okv_conf_dir allows the plugin to load and the server starts correctly. Not sure why it's not accepting the variable.

Comment: After loading check does this variable is set, and if then what value is se.

Comment: issue: set the varliable, restart mysqld, the service won't come up producing unknown variable message above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. This feature is only available in ENT version of mysql and I am using community ...